# What Happens When Schools Cannot Provide A Placement Exam?

Tags: exams, qualifying-exam

I am attempting to pass a class by exam this term, due to the fact that this is an option provided by the school and I need to in order to stay on track. I did this the previous term, but due to a variety of logistical issues, it is always delayed.

Unlike the previous time, I have not heard any word back from the faculty regarding if they are able to provide a credit for prior learning exam (i.e., a placement exam) for me.

What if they are not able to do so in time? Do I (or other students who attempt this) have a right to ask that the course be waived or some other accommodation be provided?

Comment: Since they don't have an obligation to provide classes on a schedule that's nice for you, I doubt they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schools and even individual departments probably differ greatly on how they handle such issues, so your best bet is to talk to your academic advisor as soon as possible to figure out what your options are. At many schools the "director of studies" (undergrad or graduate) for a program has some latitude to waive requirements and allow students to make substitutions—I know that was certainly the case for me when I was an undergraduate student because I had come into the major with a relatively unusual background that meant I needed to replace some classes that could not be taken (I had taken similar courses in a different "track").